# JSF navigates to the same page using navigation rule

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I am trying to configure jsf navigation rule according to jee tutorial, but I have a problem. Here is my navigation rule in faces-config.xml

```
<navigation-rule>
<from-view-id>/login.jsf</from-view-id>
<navigation-case>
    <from-action>#{userBean.login}</from-action>
    <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/home.jsf</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
<navigation-case>
    <from-action>#{userBean.login}</from-action>
    <from-outcome>failure</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/failure.jsf</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

After trying to login, method userBean.login() returns String "success" but nothing happens and in log I have warning:

```
JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, /pages/success.xhtml.
```

So why jsf tries to find success.xhtml instead of home.xhtml?

Comment: do u get any errors like java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.determineViewFromActionOutcome(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:1204? Are you using seam-faces by any chance?

Comment: @Mahendran Ayyarsamy Kandiar No NullPointerException and no errors. I use primefaces/jsf on wildfly 9.0.2